# Allow access from specific referrer and redirect the rest?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to allow users to access the registration URL of my service only if they paid for it, it is, my referrer is paypal.com (because after the payment, the are redirected to the registration area).

My registration link is like example.com/index.php/myapp/registration

But how can I apply that rule only for that specific path, and redirect all the others to myhomepage.php?

I tried something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?paypal.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php/myapp/registration$
RewriteRule ^myhomepage.php [NC,L]
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?paypal.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php/myapp/registration$
RewriteRule ^myhomepage.php [NC,R=302]
```

We are redirecting and using request uri instead of query string.